# PostgreSQL 9.1 not accepting connections

Tags: postgresql

After starting PostgreSQL 9.1, we see this error

> Server doesn't listen
>
> The server doesn't accept connections: the connection library reports 
>   could not connect to server: Connection refused Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting TCP/IP connections on port 5432? could not connect to server: Connection refused
>
> Is the server running on host "localhost" (::1) and accepting TCP/IP connections on port 5432? could not connect to server: Connection refused Is the server running on host "localhost" (fe80::1) and accepting TCP/IP connections on port 5432?

How can this be solved?

Comment: What OS?  Some variety of linux?

Comment: I migrated here rather than dba.SE because it's more likely to be a network stack issue (e.g. firewall) than a problem with Postgres.

Answer (score 1):

Check if PostgreSQL listens on 5432 using `netstat -lnp | grep 5432` (if you use Linux, for Windows I use some tools from SysInternals like TCPView and ProcessExplorer). It should listen, if not then check PostgreSQL logs.

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the server is really running by looking for some running `postgres` processes.
You can check the server's logfiles for startup errors.
You can check the server's configuration for the used `listen_address` and `port_number` and see if they are right.